# Limits for marginal PDF of y

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Just a small thing, say I have a PDF $f_{X}(x)$ bounded by $0<x<1$ and $-x<y<x$. When finding the marginal PDF for $y$, do I have to consider $-1<y<0$ and $0<y<1$ separately and thus have a piecewise marginal distribution for y ($f_{Y}(y)$), or can I do it altogether? Struggling to get my head round it.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not necessary to consider the marginal support separately.  Whether or not the marginal PDF *can* be expressed as a single function over its support depends on the specific joint PDF.  But as a general rule, it isn't a requirement to consider it separately.

Here is an example. Suppose $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \frac{3}{2}x, \quad 0 < x < 1, \quad -x < y < x.$$

The marginal for $Y$ is

$$f_Y(y) = \int_{x=|y|}^1 \frac{3}{2} x \, dx = \frac{3}{4}(1-|y|^2) = \frac{3}{4}(1-y^2), \quad -1 < y < 1.$$

You can see, there is no need to define $f_Y$ using piecewise notation.  The marginal density is continuous and smooth.

Here is another example.  Suppose
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = \begin{cases} \frac{3}{2}, & 0 < y < x < 1 \\ \frac{1}{2}, & -1 < -x < y < 0. \end{cases}$$
Then
$$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} \frac{3}{2}(1-y), & 0 < y < 1 \\ \frac{1}{2}(1+y), & -1 < y < 0. \end{cases}$$  In this case, the joint density is discontinuous along the segment joining $(0,0)$ to $(1,0)$, so it is natural that the marginal for $Y$ will also be discontinuous at $y = 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your response. For the first example, if you didnt use the absolute value of y, but instead did do it by splitting the limits, which would give you a piecewise distribution, would this be acceptable? Or do I in fact have to use a single integral.

Comment: @user1252633 You could split it, or you can do it using the absolute value as I have shown.  Either way, you will get the same answer, which does not need to use the absolute value because $|y|^2 = y^2$ for any real number $y$.